# Laravel console command trait method not found

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, opcache, laravel-forge

I have a Laravel project that has been deployed with Forge and had OPCache enabled using Forge. I noticed last week that when I pushed some changes, the changes that were in the views and in the controllers were present on the server, but custom artisan commands that I run don't recognize updates.

Put another way, updates to the blades are showing on the screen. Updates that I have added to the controllers are changing the way information is passed to the blade files, but I have a custom artisan command that runs a series of methods in a trait. The actual file on the server shows the new method that I pushed, but when I run the artisan command in the CLI, it says that the method cannot be found.

I have stopped, restarted, and reloaded OPCache countless times. I have restarted Nginx. I have disabled OPCache and restarted PHP. It is still saying that the method is not found. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Traits\FTPImportsTrait;

class CheckFTPImports extends Command
{
   use FTPImportsTrait;

   protected $signature = 'checkForImports';

   protected $description = 'Check for imports...';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
      $this->checkBankImports();
    }
}

-----------

<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait FTPImportsTrait;
{
   public function checkBankImports()
   {
      dd('YOU ARE NOT CRAZY');
   }
}
```

$ php artisan checkForImports

$ method checkBankImports does not exist.

UPDATE:

It has to be some sort of configuration issue on the server. I just deployed the project to a fresh DO droplet and the command works as expected.

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear && php artisan view:clear && php artisan config:cache` and etc.

Comment: it it's not seeing on class level, it may be autoload cannot see it. try: `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: if commands above will not work, so seems like You've a typo or doing something wrong, then You've to add code parts to Your question, otherwise we cannot predict.

Comment: I've tried composer dump and compose dump-autoload (although I think those are the same thing). I have also tried artisan cache:clear, artisan config:clear, aritsan view:clear (though, I'm not sure how that would help when view changes are showing up). I can't remember the last time I was this stumped.

Comment: then need more info, add to Your question what classes You have and what You're trying to do. need code! (:

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, @num8er. I copied the name of the method and pasted it into the reference to the method. I don't see how it could be a typo.

Comment: is `FTPImportsTrait` in `app\Traits` folder? php cli does not use nginx, so restarting nginx is useless, to clear opcache in cli version - no need. Also Your code is correct, I've also console command that uses trait and it works. strange...

Comment: Yes the file is in app\Traits. I even moved the function to within the command file and changed the name. It recognized the name change, but still said it wasn't found. I deployed it on a new server and it worked there. Works as predicted on my local using Homestead. It's only happening on a production server.

Comment: maybe: `php artisan clear-compiled`  ?  since in production `php artisan optimize` may compile all files together

Comment: YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER. php artisan clear-compiled worked.

Comment: great. now write answer to Your question Yourself and get upvotes from people who also stuck in same situation.

Comment: Seriously, thank you!

Comment: also change title to be more relevant: `Laravel console command trait method not found`

Comment: welcome. happy that we came to solution after long discussions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only happened in the production environment for me.

Running:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

deleted the cached version and solved my issue.

Thanks a ton to @num8er.